# My own WebPages are not shown on localhost

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, wicket

I have a Spring application with Apache Wicket (Its my first Spring-Application) and its autogenerated. If I run my application and I call it on localhost there is only shown a site with "TestDataManager is running" on it instead of the Site I call in the Main. I figured out that I have in the tests- package a class named ExampleController and its not from me. In this class is witten what is shown on localhost. But in my Main I dont call this Class.

Can Somone say how to fix this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application extends WebApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Page> getHomePage() {
        return WhatToDoPage.class;
    }

}
```

ExampleController:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @Value("TestDataManager is running")
    private String message;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String indexGet() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Your vague explanations "I did this and that" aren't sufficient to help you.

Comment: Putting a GetMapping annotation on the static main method makes absolutely no sense. You'll have to properly learn how Spring MVC works. This is way too broad for here.

Comment: I told im new to Spring

Comment: Hence the importance of properly learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot scans the classpath, finds `ExampleController` and registers it as a REST controller bean.

Later when you make a call to `/` it uses it to return the response. Since you return a String without `@GetMapping(produces = ...)` it uses `text/plain` as response content type.

Apache Wicket is not involved in your application. I am not sure why you use/tag it.

Comment: To be fair, his main class extends `WebApplication` and implements `getHomePage()` so he does have Wicket on his classpath. He's not using it, true, but it's there all right